# Rails 3.1 before_create callback doesn't fire after clone model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a model. I want to clone it. 
But after I run model.save! my before_create callback aren't fired. 
So, I'm wondering is it some trick to make rails think that this clone object is actually the new one.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the expected behavior in Rails 3.1. On the Active Record [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.1.0.rc5/activerecord/CHANGELOG#L282):

> Calling ActiveRecord::Base#clone will result in a shallow copy of the
>   record, including copying the frozen state. No callbacks will be
>   called.

You can use `dup`. It will run the `before_create` callback.

Comment: I'm so glad I had tests that uncovered this.

Comment: I had written tests in Rails 3.0.x that used `clone`, and when I switched to Rails 3.1.0, the symptom I got was `SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed` when calling `save`, due to a duplicate "id" attribute. Changing to `dup` as @htanata suggested fixed it; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should see http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/clone and http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/initialize_copy